# Symfony 3 Constraint validation Date or Datetime

Tags: symfony, validation, date, constraints, fosrestbundle

I try to validate a date (or a datetime) with the validation of a form into Symfony (3.2).

I'm using FOSRestBundle to use the json from request (because i try to develop my personnal API)

But i've try a lot of format:

- 2017-04-09
- 17-04-09
- for datetime:

  - 2017-04-09 21:12:12
  - 2017-04-09T21:12:12
  - 2017-04-09T21:12:12+01:00
- ...

But the form is not valid and i get always this error:
This value is not valid

The function of my controller

```
public function postPlacesAction(Request $request) {
    $place = new Place();
    $form = $this->createForm(PlaceType::class, $place);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->handleView($this->view(null, Response::HTTP_CREATED));
    } else {
        return $this->handleView($this->view($form->getErrors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
    }
}
```

My entity

```
class Place
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The name should not be blank.")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The address should not be blank.")
     */
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @var date
     *
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    protected $created;

    // ....
    // Getter and setter of all var
```

My entity type

```
class PlaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('address');
        $builder->add('created');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Place',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

An example of request (i'm using Postman)

- Method: POST
- Header: application/json
- Body (raw):

  ```
  {"place":{"name":"name","address":"an address","created":"1997-12-12"}}
  ```

I'm not sure that i use the right format, or if i missing anything in my files :/

Could you please switch on the light in my mind!?! :)

Thanks so much for your help.
Fabrice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem at `created` field in your form type. When you add `created` field using `$builder->add('created');` syntax, the default type `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType` will be applied and `1997-12-12` input data is a string, not a `DateTime` instance.

To fix this issue, you should pass `DateType` in second argument: `$builder->add('created', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType');`. This form type has a transformer which will transform the input data `1997-12-12` into a `DateTime` instance.

For more informations about Symfony's form types, have a look at [Form Types Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html)

Comment: Because i've set `@Assert\Date()` on the var of the entity, i think it's not necessary to put this into the form.
So i've just test your solution and i've always the same error: `{"form":{"children":{"name":{},"address":{},"created":{"errors":["This value is not valid."],"children":{"year":{},"month":{},"day":{}}}}},"errors":[]}`

Comment: Did you update your form as I said? If yes, you should add an additional option `$builder->add('created', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType', ['widget' => 'single_text']);`.

Comment: Yes, i've put: `$builder->add('created', DateType::class();`. But now with your additionnal option, it's fine! I had read the documentation, but I did not quite understand the meaning of the widget option. The solution for me is: `$builder->add('created', DateType::class, ['widget' => 'single_text']);` Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it help, the `widget` option let `DateTime` form type know what type of input data and how to render this form in the template.